# I have recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 to dual boot with Windows 7, but upon startup, the grub menu does not appear and boots into Windows 7

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I am running a single SSD. My motherboard has UEFI bios, though I'm not sure that helps.  I've tried holding shift on multiple startups without success.

Comment: Did you try disabling secure boot? Also,you tried to run boot-repair as described [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/228069/169736)?

Comment: As Mr Rod Smith says ,Boot Repair can often fix such problems, but sometimes it can't. If it fails, post back with a link to the diagnostic information that Boot Repair generates. (It can upload this data to a Web site and give you the URL; post that URL.)

Answer (score 2):

Boot from your Ubuntu Live DVD and try this tool-
[Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

Comment: Also read through the following thread, the links mentioned there may help you - http://askubuntu.com/questions/331947/i-installed-ubuntu-13-04-alongside-with-windows-8-64bit-but-after-installation-i/332382#332382

Comment: Boot Repair can often fix such problems, but sometimes it can't. If it fails, post back with a link to the diagnostic information that Boot Repair generates. (It can upload this data to a Web site and give you the URL; post that URL.)

Answer (score 0):

The likely problem is that the Windows Master Boot Record (MBR) is installed on your SSD.

You probably need to boot into your Linux from DVD (rescue mode) or USB drive, then write the grub MBR to your SSD by doing something like:

```
grub-install /dev/sda
```

This assumes your SSD is named /dev/sda

Comment: This answer could be correct if the computer is booting in BIOS mode; however, most computers sold in the last couple of years boot in EFI mode instead. The original question specifies an EFI-capable firmware, but it's not clear if it's actually booting Windows in EFI mode. If so, it could be that Linux was installed in BIOS mode, in which case an EFI boot loader for Linux must be installed. Boot Repair can do this, or it can be done [manually.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/)

Answer (score -1):

I would guess that you chose the wrong place to install grub. Try to install it in the mbr of your drive. I do not know what your bios lets you choose to boot from (drives or also partitions), but since you have only one drive it should be okay. But it should work if you should reinstall grub using a livecd.

Maybe you could provide more information. What is the holding shift part about? Are you trying to get into the BIOS?

Best solution would probably to use [Rescatux](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/rescatux/). This distro is designed to solve problems like yours.

Hope I could help you,
Phil

Comment: I saw from other answers that holding the left shift upon boot could manually enter grub.

Comment: If you are in the grub boot menu. But your problem is that grub is not installed where the pc is looking for at boot-up. Try the live cd solution. Either Rescatux or one in the other answers.

Comment: why -1 please explain...